# Navbar element issue

Tags: html, css

I created the navbar and put the item to be in the center by using css property

```
header
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: var(--black);
    padding: 1rem 7%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

but the items are moving to right side of the navbar .

[here is the code needed to be fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs7hM.png)

[This is how navbar looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8uoH.png)

I was trying to allign the items of navbar in the center .

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, this is just one half simple way, mimicking `div`'s

```css
:root {
  --width: 600px;
}
header
{
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  width: var(--width);
}
nav {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
nav-item {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  color: #fff;
  /* text-align: center; */
  /* width: calc(var(--width)/4); */
}
```

```html
<header>
 <nav>
  <nav-item>1</nav-item>
  <nav-item>2</nav-item>
  <nav-item>3</nav-item>
  <nav-item>4</nav-item>
 </nav>
</header>
```